# Removing the barrier after the collision?

Tags: c#, collision-detection

I'm making a game (Breakout) and I have a question,

The question is how can I remove the barriers after they get hit by the ball?
Of course, the ball must be able to go through the track after that (like Breakout game in general)

the next question is that can I make the barriers in run time mode?

Thanks

[image: picture]

```
private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ball.Top += step;
        ball.Left += stepleft;

        //board simulate collision
        bool collisonX = ball.Location.X + ball.Width > board.Location.X && ball.Location.X < board.Location.X + board.Width;
        bool collisonY = ball.Top + ball.Height == board.Location.Y || ball.Top + ball.Height - 1 == board.Location.Y;

        //board2(button1) simulate collision
        bool collisonX2 = ball.Location.X + ball.Width > board2.Location.X && ball.Location.X < board2.Location.X + board2.Width;
        bool collisonY2 = ball.Top + ball.Height == board2.Location.Y || ball.Top + ball.Height - 1 == board2.Location.Y;

        //Collision the ball with under buttons 
        bool collsionButtonY = ball.Top - ball.Height == board2.Location.Y || ball.Top - ball.Height == board2.Location.Y - 1;

        //collision leftwall 
        bool leftWall = ball.Left == 0 || ball.Left == -1 || ball.Left == 1;
        //collision rightwall 
        bool topWall = ball.Top == 0 || ball.Top == -1 || ball.Top == 1;

        bool bottomWall = collisonX && collisonY;
        bool toppWall = collisonX2 && collisonY2;

        //collision 
        bool barrier = collisonX2 && collsionButtonY; 

        bool collisionLeft = ((ball.Location.Y + ball.Height >= board2.Location.Y) && (ball.Location.Y <= board2.Location.Y + board2.Height) && (ball.Location.X + ball.Width >= board2.Location.X) && (ball.Location.X <= board2.Location.X + board2.Height));

        //rightwall
        bool rightWall = ball.Left + ball.Width == this.ClientSize.Width || ball.Left + ball.Width == this.ClientSize.Width - 1;
        // sidewall = collision rightwall or leftwall 
        bool sideWall = leftWall || rightWall;

        //Check the ball hit the ground 
        bool check = ball.Top + ball.Height < this.ClientSize.Height;

        //if topWall true,This means that the ball is hit to the topwall
        if (topWall)
        {
            flagBottom = false;
            flagTop = true;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                step = 2;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                step = 2;
            }
        }
        //if bottomWall true,This means that the ball is hit to the board
        else if (bottomWall)
        {
            flagBottom = true;
            flagTop = false;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;
            }
        }
        //if barrier true and flagbottom true,This means that the ball is hit to the board2(button1)
        else if (barrier && flagBottom)
        {
            collisionLeft = false;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;
            }
        }
        //if toppWall true and flagTop true,This means that the ball is hit to The top button is hit 
        else if (toppWall && flagTop)
        {
            collisionLeft = false;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                step = step * -1;
            }
        }
        else if (flagTop && collisionLeft)
        {
            barrier = false;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                stepleft = -2;
                step = 2;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                stepleft = 2;
                step = 2;
            }
        }
        else if (flagBottom && collisionLeft)
        {
            barrier = false;
            if (stepleft > 0)
            {
                stepleft = -2;
                step = -2;
            }
            else if (stepleft < 0)
            {
                stepleft = 2;
                step = -2;
            }
        }
        else if (sideWall)
        {
            //if leftwall true,This means that the ball is hit to the left side wall
            if (leftWall)
            {
                if (flagTop)
                {
                    stepleft = 2;
                }
                else if (flagBottom)
                {
                    stepleft = 2;
                }
            }
            //if rightWall true,This means that the ball is hit to the left side wall
            else if (rightWall)
            {
                if (flagTop)
                {
                    stepleft = -2;
                }
                else if (flagBottom)
                {
                    stepleft = -2;
                }
            }
        }
        //check if ckeck==ture,this mean the ball is hit the ground
        else if (!check)
        {
            timer1.Enabled = false;
        }
    }

    private void board_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            MouseDownLocation = e.Location;
        }
    }

    private void board_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Left)
        {
            board.Left = e.X + board.Left - MouseDownLocation.X;
        }
```

Comment: It would help, if we only knew what objects ball, board, board2 etc. are.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to learn use lists and proper use of classes.

For example :

```
public class GameObject{

  public GameObject(int x, int y, int width, int height){
     this.X = x;
     this.Y = y;
     this.Width = width;
     this.Height = height;
  }

  int X;
  int Y;
  int Width;
  int Height;

  public bool DetectCollision(bool Ball){
     //code to detect collision
  }
}
```

Then in your main class, you can do thing like that.

```
List<GameObject> gameObjects = new List<GameObject>();
gameObjects.add(new GameObject(10,10,50,50));
gameObjects.add(new GameObject(20,10,20,50));
gameObjects.add(new GameObject(30,10,50,70));
gameObjects.add(new GameObject(40,10,90,50));
```

And to detect the collisions :

```
foreach (GameObject gameObject in gameObjects){
   if (gameObject.DetectCollision(ball)){
      //do something
   }
}
```

Comment: The question is how can I remove the barriers after they get hit by the ball? Of course, the ball must be able to go through the track after that (like Breakout game in general)